# Is it possible to mint an NFT in Solana "unrevealed" and then reveal it later on?

Tags: blockchain, nft, solana

I'm trying to orchestrate an NFT presale on Solana, such that the collectible is revealed at a specific time after purchase. Is that possible on Solana and how?

Answer (score 1):

My guess, you can create an NFT (SPL Token) collection where each token is wrapped with metadata for unrevealed NFT (kind of mystery box metadata, same for all), and later at a specific date you can run a script that will replace each NFT's metadata from the collection with revealed metadata since we can rewrite account data for SPL Token (NFT) at any point.

2nd option is to use a pattern similar to Raydium Dropzone where users can redeem NFT at a specific date with NFT tickets.
Details: https://raydium.medium.com/introducing-dropzone-2095bd78930c